# SerializationSchema open method was not called

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I implemented the
`SerializationSchema` for `KinesisStreamsSink`, and I initialized the SerializationSchema in the 'Open' method. But I found the 'Open' method was actually not called by the Flink. Any body knows this issue?

Because my implementation of the SerializationSchema depends on some class that is not Serializable, I have to initialize it in the open method on the runtime.

I used the `KinesisStreamSink` followed the guide of the flink document which likes:

```
inesisStreamsSink<String> kdsSink =
    KinesisStreamsSink.<String>builder()
        .setKinesisClientProperties(sinkProperties)                               // Required
        .setSerializationSchema(new CustomizedSchema())                         // Required
        .setPartitionKeyGenerator(element -> String.valueOf(element.hashCode()))  // Required
        .setStreamName("your-stream-name")                                        // Required
        .setFailOnError(false)                                                    // Optional
        .setMaxBatchSize(500)                                                     // Optional
        .setMaxInFlightRequests(50)                                               // Optional
        .setMaxBufferedRequests(10_000)                                           // Optional
        .setMaxBatchSizeInBytes(5 * 1024 * 1024)                                  // Optional
        .setMaxTimeInBufferMS(5000)                                               // Optional
        .setMaxRecordSizeInBytes(1 * 1024 * 1024)                                 // Optional
        .build();
```

In the code, the `CustomizedSchema` was not properly initialized cause the open method was not called.

Comment: Could you attach the codes here? It's hard to figure out the problem without reading the codes.

Comment: I add the sample code from flink document in the description and thank you for your reply.

Comment: Does the sink get data? the customized schema will be called only when there is data coming to the sink.

Comment: @Shankar, thanks for reply. The customized schema was called, but failed because it was not initialized. The initialization logic was in the ```open``` method of schema, but it was not called when the flink job was initializing.

Comment: Can confirm that the overwritten open() method is not called in a subclass of org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SerializationSchema. 

@EricZhang can you maybe also provide the example code for your `CustomizedSchema`. Or did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Same happens on the KinesisFirehoseSink in flink 1.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Flink 1.15. It is resolved in 1.16 with this [PR](https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/20473).

The proposed workaround for Flink version 1.15 is a null-check and lazy initialization. See [discussion](https://lists.apache.org/thread/mcrznwtnbs9ky9k3j9lwhcf89x3nvr53) on the Flink user mailing list.

Comment: Yes. At last, I initialize it with null-check and lazy initialization. Will upgrade to 1.6 in the future. Thanks for your answer.